# How to make a wet shader with running raindrops etc?

Tags: shaders, procedural

Im curious how I would go about creating a wet shader that looks a bit like the image below. the image is of need for speed rivals because it has quite a cool running water effect. Water droplets are one thing but it would be nice to actually get streaks etc.

it would be cool if someone had an animated solution but its not necessary

[image]

Comment: Hi. What do you have so far and where, *specifically*, did you get stuck?

Comment: @RayMairlot I havent really done anything of value yet. I'm not having a specific issue, I just dont know how to make a shader like that

Comment: If you just want to make a shader which looks like the photo, you have to use wet overlay for the roughness, something like this: https://www.textures.com/browse/overlays/114557#procedural. If you want to change it dynamically by the droplets, you have to use the dynamic paint function.

Comment: Searched for Raindrops here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121131/how-to-make-a-procedural-node-setup-to-for-raindrop-effect-for-eevee or here
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60248/creating-a-rain-effect/60251#60251

Comment: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/animated-raindrop-texture  /  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aihjJ12DR8  /  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8kw0a2ZeI